# How To Use Tensorflow.where in the same way as np.where?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, loss-function

I am trying to make a custom loss function which calculates MSE, but ignores all points where the truth is below some threshold (close to 0). I can achieve this using numpy arrays in the following way.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.normal(size=(4,4))
b = np.random.normal(size=(4,4))
temp_a = a[np.where(a>0.5)] # Your threshold condition
temp_b = b[np.where(a>0.5)]
mse = mean_squared_error(temp_a, temp_b)
```

But I don't see how I would do this with keras backend. My custom loss function does not work because numpy can not operate on tensors.

```
def customMSE(y_true, y_pred):
    '''
    Correct predictions of 0 do not affect performance.
    '''
    y_true_ = y_true[tf.where(y_true>0.1)] # Your threshold condition
    y_pred_ = y_pred[tf.where(y_true>0.1)]
    mse = K.mean(K.square(y_pred_ - y_true_), axis=1)
    return mse
```

But when I do this, I am returned with the error

````
ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 3 for '{{node customMSE/strided_slice}} = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT64, T=DT_FLOAT, begin_mask=0, ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=0, new_axis_mask=0, shrink_axis_mask=1](cond_2/Identity_1, customMSE/strided_slice/stack, customMSE/strided_slice/stack_1, customMSE/strided_slice/Cast)' with input shapes: [?,?,?,?], [1,?,4], [1,?,4], [1].```
````

Comment: Loss function will be executed in graph mode, and numpy functions are not available there. Use instead `tf.where` (`import tensorflow as tf`).

Comment: Oh. On the first call to tf.where, I return a value error ```Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 3```. Not sure what to make of it. It has to do with ```y_true[tf.where(y_true>01.)]``` @Kaveh

Comment: I have exactly replaced np.where with tf.where. Do I have to reshape the input tensors then, to be 1D using tf? @Kaveh

Comment: What are you trying to do in custom loss function?

Comment: @Kaveh I want to calculate the MSE, but only for predictions where the truth is not 0 or close to 0. I want to ignore those.

Comment: you mean if the corresponding y_true of a y_pred was less than 0.1, you want to ignore the loss?

Comment: @Kaveh yes. I want the network to learn the patterns in the image, but regular MSE biases it towards predicting 0 really well.

Comment: If so, you used of tf.where and np.where incorrectly. I will post how you can do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tf.where` instead of `np.where` in loss function.

And if you want to make the loss of predictions which their corresponding ground truth value is lower than a threshold you may write custom function like this:

```
def my_loss_threshold(threshold):
    def my_loss(y_true,y_pred):
        # keep predictions pixels where their corresponding y_true is above a threshold
        y_pred = tf.gather_nd(y_pred, tf.where(y_true>=threshold))
        # keep image pixels where they're above a threshold
        y_true = tf.gather_nd(y_true, tf.where(y_true>=threshold))
        # compute MSE between filtered pixels
        loss = tf.square(y_true-y_pred)
        # return mean of losses
        return tf.reduce_mean(loss)
    return my_loss 

model.compile(loss=my_loss_threshold(threshold=0.1), optimizer="adam")
```

I wrapped loss function to another function, so you can pass threshold as a hyperparameter to model compile.

Comment: It's not that we want to set the loss to 0, we don't want to count it at all. It shouldn't enter into the sum of loss, it should simply be ignored. If there are 100 pixels on the image, and there are 10 non-zero pixels, the MSE should be summed only for those 10 pixels. Does this do that?

Comment: It works if you set ```loss = tf.where(y_true<0.1)```. Is it possible to block out only when both y_true and y_pred < 0.1? ```loss = tf.where(y_true<0.1 and y_pred<0.1)``` throws an error, unfortunately.

Comment: @mmont I edited my answer, in a way you can ignore the loss of predictions, which their corresponding `y_true` is lower than a threshold.

Comment: This looks to be right, but I am not at my pc. However, what if I wanted to filter out based on two conditions: 1. y_true < thres & 2. y_pred < thres? It doesn’t work with tf.where(). I’d basically look at a pixel and only keep it based on whether it’s corresponding values in two other tensors meet a condition. Easy enough with numpy, but quite hard with tensors @Kaveh

Comment: @mmont If you want to get a precise answer, you should provide a precise question of what you want. It's not a good idea to change the question at anytime you get a response. Specify what do you want to do exactly, and then ask your question.

Comment: I only ask because I had already implemented the same technique (as mentioned in one of my comments). It does not lead to a good loss function, so I asked if you could change the solution. Anyway, the precise question is asked here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68719414/how-to-create-a-loss-function-with-mse-that-uses-tf-where-to-ignore-certain-el?noredirect=1#comment121452958_68719414