# How To Create A Loss Function with MSE that Uses tf.where() to ignore certain elements

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

Here is the function currently. Here, it removes from the MSE any values where y_true is less than a threshold (here, it is 0.1).

```
def my_loss(y_true,y_pred):
    loss = tf.square(y_true-y_pred)
    # if any y_true is less than a threshold (say 0.1) 
    # the element is removed from loss, and does not affect MSE
    loss = tf.where(y_true<0.1)
    # return mean of losses
    return tf.reduce_mean(loss)
```

This one compiles, but the network doesn't ever learn to predict 0 well. Instead, I would like to eliminate only those values where both y_true and y_pred are less than some threshold. This is because it needs to first learn how to predict 0, before ignoring those points later on in the training.

This, however, does not compile.

```
def my_better_loss(y_true,y_pred):
    loss = tf.square(y_true-y_pred)
    # remove all elements where BOTH y_true & y_pred < threshold
    loss = tf.where(y_true<0.1 and y_pred<0.1)
    # return mean of losses
    return tf.reduce_mean(loss)
```

It leads to the following error.

```
  (0) Invalid argument:  The second input must be a scalar, but it has shape [25,60,60]
         [[{{node replica_1/customMSE/cond/switch_pred/_51}}]]
  (1) Invalid argument:  The second input must be a scalar, but it has shape [25,60,60]
         [[{{node replica_1/customMSE/cond/switch_pred/_51}}]]
         [[customMSE/cond/Squeeze/_59]]
  (2) Invalid argument:  The second input must be a scalar, but it has shape [25,60,60]
         [[{{node replica_1/customMSE/cond/replica_1/customMSE/Less/_55}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_function_4715]

Function call stack:
train_function -> train_function -> train_function
```

Edit:

To be more specific. Say our threshold is 0.5:

```
y_true = [0.3, 0.4, 0.6, 0.7]
y_pred = [0.2, 0.7, 0.5, 1]
```

Then the loss function would compute mse with the first element removed, since both y_pred[0] and y_true[0] are less than threshold.

```
# MSE would be computed between
y_true = [0.4, 0.6, 0.7]
#and
y_pred = [0.7, 0.5, 1]
```

Comment: u can easily do this but if all elements of y_pred and y_true in the batch are less then the threshold the loss will be nan

Comment: True! Is there any way around that? Could I check for ```if loss == np.nan``` then ```loss = 0``` which is acceptable since it is predicting that image correctly. What implementation did you have in mind?

Comment: you can simply put all below the threshold equal to zero (like a relu implementation) in this way there is no nan problem when computing loss

Comment: @MarcoCerliani However, I want there to be non-zero loss when ```truth <= threshold``` but ```pred > threshold```. Without that, the network won't be penalized by just putting non-zero values everywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time it results in undesirable behaviours or errors if you use the python short-circuit `and` operator in codes that convert into graph mode because the python short-circuit `and` operator cannot be overloaded. To do element-wise and operation for tensors, use `tf.math.logical_and`.

Besides, `tf.where` is not necessary here and it is likely to be slower. Masking is preferred. Example codes:

```
@tf.function
def better_loss(y_true,y_pred):
  loss = tf.square(y_true - y_pred)
  # ignore elements where BOTH y_true & y_pred < 0.1
  mask = tf.cast(tf.logical_or(y_true >= 0.1, y_pred >= 0.1) ,tf.float32)
  loss *= mask
  return tf.reduce_sum(loss) / tf.reduce_sum(mask)
```

Comment: Is there a way to increase loss (penalize) where y_true > 0.1 & y_pred < 0.1? I see how we could ignore those elements, but is there a way to penalize instead?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to confused with the `tf.where` usage. From [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where) it can be sen that tf.where should take three parameters else it will simply return `None` as mentioned here

```
tf.where(
    condition, x=None, y=None, name=None
)
```

That's why your loss isn't helping in learning anything, cause it returns `None` always no matter how.

For your questions if you want to check both condition and then imply a loss this is how you should do it.

Let's say for `y_true!=0` and `y_pred!=0` you want to give losses, `some_loss1` and `some_loss2` respectively, then the total loss can be computed by nesting `tf.where` as

```
some_loss1=tf.constant(1000.0) #say
some_loss12=tf.constant(1000.0) #say

loss = tf.where(y_pred<0.1,tf.where(y_true<0.1,tf.constant(0.0),some_loss1),some_loss2)
```

This shall penalize both `y_pred and y_true`.

Also if you want to add this loss to your MSE loss, then create different variable names as it resigned the already obtained MSE value to this mask loss.

Comment: From tensorflow.org: This operator has two modes: in one mode both x and y are provided, in another mode neither are provided. condition is always expected to be a tf.Tensor of type bool.